# What does the installation of linux-{image,headers}-generic-lts-backport-natty do?

Tags: apt, command-line

What do these command do?

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty \
                     linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

Does it install just a new Linux version or something more?

And what about:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty \
                   linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

Does it just remove the packages installed by the previous command? (or does it more?)

If I am correct in all cases why it doesn't work? I get an error, so it means it's not true and something else had happened?

Edit:
as it was said that second command doesn't remove it, then would this command remove it? `aptitude autoremove`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/sudo.8.html) command is allowing you to run the apt-get command with admin privileges.
The [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html) command is installing (first example) or removing (second example) software packages. "Purge" simply means configuration files are deleted too.
For explanations of the various packages, you can check [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: it didn't remove and i got error while running it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what it does. Technically it does not install Linux, it installs the Linux kernel.
But it only works if you're running Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal.

`sudo` gives you superuser privileges (required for administrative tasks such as installing software).
`apt-get` is a package manager that is used to install and uninstall packages.
Then 'install' and 'purge' are the options that you give the package manager, and what follows is a list of packages.

The kernel is a required component and necessary for the system to operate. Occasionally there are updates for it, and the package manager will update it if there is a later version available. Run `update-manager` to update your system including the kernel.

Comment: i had number 32 but user said to install this one and it will fix previous problems, but in new version drivers don't work

Comment: also i went to 32 when running this command, is it ok? or i should have run it on new one? i still see it in GNU loader

Comment: I have removed it through Synaptic Package Manager and error is gone but when computer boot ups I still can choose 2.6.38 kernel in GNU loader, how I can remove it from there?